# Changing the text appearance of title bar in android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the text appearance of the title bar im using on my activity. In depth: i want to change the fontFamily to sans-serif-thin.

This is what i tried to do among various other approaches:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/jammi_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/jammi_red_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/jammi_green</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong? I'm working on a Nexus 5 with API 21. Minimum API for my App is 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did this in my app. This is part of my MainActivity code:

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/CustomFont.ttf");
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Don't forget to put your .ttf file into the asset folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it programmatically (put your Typeface file in asset folder), it works for me:

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id","android");

TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);

private Typeface tfLogo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Wolf.otf");

yourTextView.setTypeface(tfLogo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said your minimum sdk level is 16, so do not use the `AppCompat` package, it is for older versions for backward compatability. Use one of the platform themes such as `Theme.Holo.Light.Dark.ActionBar` that does have not the `AppCompat`in it as the parent.